# Flashing nordic n51802

Tags: microcontroller, bluetooth-low-energy, reverse-engineering, nrf51822

I have a Chinese rip-off game pad, which has an n51802 which is by nordic. I want to flash my own firmware but i’m unable to find any information about it. I can put it in DFU mode, so it is flashable, i have the original firmware from the company - but reversing it would take too much time.

It seems very similar to nrf51822 but i don’t know if they are binary compatible, have same address space etc.

What can i do to find more information about developing for it?

Comment: It's mentioned in the release notes of the nRF SDK, so you should probably start there and other manufacturer info sources.  Finding offsite resources is not within the mission of SE sites.  Likely the flashing algorithm is comparable to the more well-known members of the family but it's possible something like openocd might need small changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it may be the nRF51802 or nRF51822 (you might have read the digits in the wrong order). Quite popular part. [You can get the SDK, SoftDevices and all manuals from Nordic's website.](https://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/Bluetooth-low-energy/nRF51822) SEGGER provides free [Embedded Studio](https://www.segger.com/products/development-tools/embedded-studio/) for Nordic chips.

You will also need a debug probe ("JTAG") to flash the device, for example a [J-Link EDU](https://www.segger.com/products/debug-probes/j-link/models/j-link-edu/) or FTDI adapter + OpenOCD.

Comment: The premise of this response is false **The nRF51802 is an actual part**, mentioned in the Nordic SDK's release notes.

Answer (score -2):

I ripped off a health-band and it had N51802 SOC powered by a tiny LiPo.
[image: FitBit health band]

When I lifted the display on the back of the PCB there were 6-test/contact points:
[image: Contacts below the display]

Most probably these can be used to program the SOC. I an not going to try figuring that out as the circuit & components are too small for me to solder and use it for any practical use. I needed the tiny LiPo for another project.

Comment: It's possible that you're right, but a good guess is not a good answer. If there was a link to documentation listing what these points were then this would be good. This would perhaps have been better as a comment when you have enough reputation for one.